# Hard drive detected but OS doesn't boot up (both Linux and Win10/11) from it

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios

BIOS (GIGABYTE B550M Pro-p rev 1.0) detects both my NVME SSD and bootable usb fine.

I have Arch Linux installed on my NVME and [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) on the USB (holds Arch and Win 10/11 ISOs).

When I select either of them, I get the menu option from which the desired OS is selected:

- SSD: Systemd-boot option appears and counts down from 3 secs to boot into Arch, but instead it reboots and loops back to systemd-boot menu.
- USB: Arch/Win 10/Win 11 selection makes USB led blinks fast, indicating contents being read. Then the blinking stops, PC reboots and its back to the menu option (in this instance, it is set as the 1st boot option).

I have used the same NVME and Ventoy USB, on my MSI and ASRock mobos and they both boot all the OSs just fine.

What is the reason for the mobo (or BIOS) not booting the OS?
What does it require to boot the OS?
Power Supply/CPU (AMD 5600G) and RAM sticks seem all fine.

My other attempts at updating the BIOS, restoring default BIOS settings and CMOS battery reset, have yielded no success.

Any other insights?
Let me know if you require any further clarifications

Comment: Try to enter the BIOS and do Reset.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned - the CMOS battery BIOS reset also did not bring any success.

Comment: Something is wrong with the SSD boot. Did it ever work? If yes, when did it stop working?

Comment: The NVME SSD works fine, since I did successfully install the OSs on it using my MSI and ASRock mobos to install the OSs.

Comment: But you say that you can't boot from it?

Comment: I can't boot from it when its on the GIGABYTE motherboard. So since it works fine on MSI and ASRock mobos, the NVME can be ruled out as being bad.

Comment: The question is if the GIGABYTE motherboard supports this SSD, or whether you have connected it to the correct slot. What is the SSD? Please indicate on [this schema](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/TUF-Gaming/TUF-GAMING-B550M-PLUS/) where it's connected.

Comment: Gigabyte supports that SSD (Socket 3, M key, type 2280 SSDs), and yes I have connected it to both the slots (CPU and PCIe) and tried it out. Needless to add, without success.

Comment: The SSD seems to be incompatible with this motherboard. Maybe GIGABYTE Support can explain.

Comment: Here is the specs: https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B550M-AORUS-PRO-P-rev-10/sp#sp
I suspect its the BIOS firmware, because the USB behavior is also similar.

Comment: What is the SSD?

Comment: See my answers above.Gigabyte supports that SSD (Socket 3, M key, type 2280 SSDs)